# Help deriving simple linear regression formulas

Tags: optimization, least-squares

I'm reading the Wikipedia article [Simple Linear Regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression) .  In the article they write a function to be minimized by choosing $\alpha$ and $\beta$:

$$Q(\alpha,\beta) = \sum_{i=0}^{n} (y_i - \alpha - \beta x_i)^2$$

They show equations for $\alpha$ and $\beta$ to minimize the function.  But, they don't show the derivation. Thus, I am trying to work through it, but I'm having difficulty....

To find $\alpha$ I'm letting $\frac{\partial Q}{\partial\alpha}=0$ and solving for $\alpha$. Similarly, to find $\beta$ I'm letting $\frac{\partial Q}{\partial\beta}=0$ and solving for $\beta$.  However, I'm finding that in both cases I'm getting the equation $\hat \alpha = \bar y - \hat \beta \bar x$.  This equation does relate $\alpha$ and $\beta$, but doesn't help you find $\beta$.

What approach could I take to find $\beta$?  I wonder I'm doing the derivative with respect to $\beta$ wrong, but I don't know.

p.s. What is distinction between bars and hats in the article?  I see both of them and think "average".

Comment: bars are for the average, whereas hats are for the estimation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One defines $\bar y = (y_1+\cdots+y_n)/n$ and similarly with $x$.  The bar means the average of the $n$ observations.

Notice that you don't have $n$ different observed values of $\alpha$ or $\beta$ --- in fact you don't have any observed values of those at all.  The idea is that $\{(x_i,y_i):i=1,\ldots,n\}$ is a sample of size $n$ taken from a large population, and $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are in effect properties of that population, whereas $\hat\alpha$ and $\hat\beta$ are estimates of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ based on the observed sample of $n$ data points.  If you toss the $n$ observed individuals back into the population and stir it up and take another random sample of size $n$, then the values of $\hat\alpha$ and $\hat\beta$ change, but the (unobservable) values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ remain the same.  Another use of the hat notation is when one writes
$$
\hat y_i = \hat\alpha+\hat\beta x_i.
$$
Notice that $\hat y_i$ has a "hat" and $x_i$ does not.  The number $\hat y_i$ is the $i$th "fitted value".  It is an estimate of the average $y$-value among members of the population for which the $x$-value is $x_i$.  The difference $\hat\varepsilon_i=y_i-\hat y_i$ is the $i$th **residual**, also equal to $y_i-(\hat\alpha+\hat\beta x_i)$, not to be confused with the $i$th **error** $\varepsilon_i=y_i-(\alpha+\beta x_i)$.  The *residuals* are observable; the *errors* are not.  The *residuals* must satisfy the two constraints $\sum_{i=1}^n \hat\varepsilon_i=0$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n \hat\varepsilon_i x_i=0$; the *errors* are subject to no such constraints.  That there are *two* such linear constraints is why one says there are $n-2$ degrees of freedom for error.

I don't use derivatives to find $\hat\beta$ and $\hat\alpha$; instead I talk about matrices and orthogonal projections.  But let's see if I can do it using derivatives:

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial Q}{\partial\alpha} & = -2\sum_{i=0}^{n} (y_i - \alpha - \beta x_i) =0 \tag1 \\[10pt]
\frac{\partial Q}{\partial\beta} & = -2\sum_{i=0}^{n} (y_i - \alpha - \beta x_i)x_i = 0 \tag2
\end{align}
$$

From $(1)$ we conclude that
$$
\alpha = \bar y - \beta \bar x. \tag 3
$$
Thus the least-squares line must pass through the "point of averages" $(\bar x,\bar y)$, which is just the average of the observed data points $(x_i,y_i),\ i=1,\ldots,n$.

Now substitute $(3)$ for $\alpha$ in the $(2)$:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n (y_i - (\bar y - \beta \bar x) -\beta x_i)x_i,
$$
or:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n ((y_i-\bar y) -\beta(x_i-\bar x))x_i=0
$$
$$
\beta = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (y_i-\bar y)x_i }{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\bar x)x_i}.
$$

That that is the same as
$$
\beta = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (y_i-\bar y)(x_i-\bar x) }{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\bar x)(x_i-\bar x)}
$$
I leave as an exercise in algebra for the moment, but I'll post more on it if you have questions about that.