# Regress $X_1$ on $X_2$ through $X_K$

Tags: statistics, regression, linear-regression

I'm new to linear regression so I don't really understand this question

> Consider the general multiple-regression equation
> $$Y=\beta_0 +\beta_1 x_1 +\beta_2 x_2 + \dots + \beta_k x_k +\epsilon$$
> An alternative procedure for calculating the least-quares coefficient $\hat{\beta}_1$ is as follow:
>
> 1. Regress $Y$ on $X_2$ through $X_k$, obtaining $E_{Y|2\dots k}$.
> 2. Regress $X_1$ $X_2$ through $X_k$, obtaining $E_{1|2\dots k}$.
> 3. Regress the residuals $E_{Y|2\dots k}$ on the residuals $E_{1|2\dots k}$. The slope for this simple regression is the multiple - regression slope for $X_1$, which is $\hat{\beta}_1$.

So for 1), I think it as $E(y|x_2,x_3,\dots,x_k)=\beta_0+\beta_1E(x_1)+\beta_2x_2+\dots+\beta_kx_k$ right? However, I'm not sure how to do for number 2 and 3. Can somebody please give me any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, a review of multiple regression methodology. When you perform a regression of a response variable $Y$ on predictor variables $X_0, X_1, X_2,\ldots, X_k$, the procedure is to construct a **design matrix** $X$ that holds the predictors as columns. The multiple regression model then becomes $Y=X\beta+\epsilon$ where $\beta$ and $\epsilon$ are column vectors of appropriate size. The **least squares estimators** $\hat\beta$ for the unknown vector $\beta$ will then satisfy the **normal equations**
$(X^TX)\hat\beta=X^TY$, whence $$\hat\beta=(X^TX)^{-1}X^TY.\tag{$\dagger$}$$ The **residual vector** $E$ is defined as the difference between the observed $Y$ and the predicted $\hat Y:=X\hat\beta$, so that
$$E := Y-X\hat\beta=Y-X(X^TX)^{-1}X^TY.$$ It is convenient to introduce the **hat matrix** $H:=X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T$ so we can write the residual vector in the tidier form $$E=(I-H)Y.\tag{$\ast$}$$

---

Now apply this to your situation. In parts (1) and (2) you are being asked to consider $X_2$ through $X_k$ (and an intercept term) as predictors in a model. For part (1) the model is
$$E(y\mid x_2,\ldots,x_k)=\alpha_0+\alpha_2x_2 +\cdots+\alpha_kx_k,$$ whereas for (2) it's
$$E(x_1\mid x_2,\ldots,x_k)=\gamma_0+\gamma_2x_2 +\cdots+\gamma_kx_k,$$ for unknown parameters $\alpha_0,\ldots,\alpha_k$ and $\gamma_0,\ldots,\gamma_k$ to be estimated.
So your design matrix is the same for parts (1) and (2): You pack a column vector of ones, and the regressor columns $X_2$ through $X_k$ into your design matrix $X_{2..k}$. In part (1) the response variable is $Y$, whereas in (2) the response variable is $X_1$. Construct the hat matrix $H_{2..k}$. The residuals for these two regressions are then given by formula ($\ast$):
$$E_{Y\mid 2..k}=(I-H_{2..k})Y,\qquad E_{X_1\mid 2..k}=(I-H_{2..k})X_1.$$

In part (3) you perform a simple linear regression of column vector $E_{Y\mid 2..k}$ (treated as a response) on column vector $E_{X_1\mid 2..k}$ (treated as a predictor). Apply the [usual formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/641836/215011) to obtain the slope of the regression line. Alternatively, you can use the matrix formulation to set up a design matrix (with two columns) and compute the least squares estimator of the slope using $(\dagger)$.

Notice that in this context the column vectors you are dealing with both sum to zero (because the [residuals sum to zero](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/494181/215011) whenever there is an intercept term in the model); this gives an especially concise form for the slope of the simple linear regression line.

Comment: I'm not OP, but I just wanted to say that this was better than any explanation I've found in textbooks
$$$$
Have a nice day comrade  :-)

Comment: Thank you, so I got it wrong right from the beginning.